# Read string into a variable until a certain word in BASH

Tags: macos, bash

I have a program that outputs something like this:

```
stuff=Some text with spaces and other $pecial characters stuff2=1 stuff3=0
```

I am trying to get all of that string up until stuff2=1 in a variable, so the variable would be:

```
stuff=Some text with spaces and other $special characters
```

I have tried this:

```
for word in $output
while [ $word != "stuff2=1" ]
do
   var+=" "$word
done
done
```

but all I get is "stuff=Some" over and over again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
stuff='Some text with spaces and other $pecial characters stuff2=1 stuff3=0'

var=""
for word in $stuff
do
  if [ "$word" == "stuff2=1" ]
     then
    break
  fi
  if [ "$var" != "" ]
  then
    var="${var} "
  fi
  var="${var}${word}"
done
echo "$var"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with simple bash parameter expansion:

```
line='stuff=Some text with spaces and other $pecial characters stuff2=1 stuff3=0'
truncated=${line% stuff2=1*}
echo "$truncated"
```

```
stuff=Some text with spaces and other $pecial characters
```

It's critical to quote the variable when you need to "dereference" it.

Answer (score 2):

Can be accomplished in bash itself

```
stuff=${stuff/stuff2=1*/}
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
$ eval $(sed "s/=/='/;s/ [^ ]*=.*/'/")
```

```
$ echo $stuff
Some text with spaces and other $pecial characters
```